# Simplifying $i |x|$

Tags: complex-numbers, absolute-value

Is there any way that one could condense the expression $$i |x|$$
where $i$ is the imaginary unitto get the $i$ inside of the absolute value? I have not been able to find any way to do so but I feel like there has to be because it gives me the desired result when simplifying a log expression with absolute values.

Comment: what is i? The complex number? Then you cannot get i inside, because i|x| is imaginary while |y| is real for any y

Comment: Yes, $i$ is the imaginary unit. Thank you

Comment: What's the actual log expression that you have?

Comment: $i \ln{| x+\sqrt{x^2-1} | } - i \ln i$

Comment: I am aware that I could solve for $ i \ln i$ to get $\frac{- \pi}{2}$ but my goal is to eliminate the constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if $x=0$. If there was some $y$ such that $i|x|=|y|$ then as $|y|\in\mathbb{R}$, then $i|x|\in\mathbb{R}$. This implies that $x=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not think of using the fact that the range of absolute value is only real numbers.